# Is it possible to have unique together constraint on a SET of columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    bar1 int,
    bar2 int,
    type varchar(16),
    FOREIGN KEY bar1 REFERENCES bar(id),
    FOREIGN KEY bar2 REFERENCES bar(id)
);

ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT unique_link (bar1, bar2);

INSERT INTO foo (bar1, bar2, type) VALUES (1, 2, 'simple link')
--next line should fail, as {2, 1} as a set is already present, just in a different order
INSERT INTO foo (bar1, bar2, type) VALUES (2, 1, 'simple link')
```

Is it possible in any way? Maybe with some triggers maybe, or some auto calculated hashes of the bar* columns? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a unique index for that:

```
create unique index on foo ( least(bar1,bar2), greatest(bar1,bar2) );
```

Comment: Thanks, you do need the `least`, `greatest` functions!

Comment: @HodossySzabolcs Note that this solution does not prohibit `bar1=bar2`.

Comment: @Akina: that is true. But that can be achieved with a simple check constraint - although I didn't see anything rin the question that would suggest that this is  needed

Comment: Of course, maybe it is allowed. But most importantly, the question author is warned if he forgot...

Comment: Sure, it would not happen, but good to be reminded of it! Thanks @Akina